# Is L = {a^n a^n b^m |m, n ≥ 0} a regular or irregular language?

Tags: computer-science, regular-language, dfa, formal-languages, pumping-lemma

I have troubles in solving/proving this problem. I can understand that in a non regular no Finite State Automaton/Machine can be written that validates and accepts this input since it lacks a memory component. (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

The wikipedia entry on Regular Language also lists this example, but does not provide a (mathematical) proof why it is not regular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This language is accepted by the regular expression `(aa)*b*`, so yes, it is a regular language.

Comment: You mean that because n*n >=0 and m*n*n >=0?

Comment: I mean because there is no dependence between n and m. So you can treat them separately. And `{ a^n a^n | n ≥ 0 }` is simply `a`, repeated any even number of times.

Comment: @einpoklum Did you mean  `a^n` ?

Answer (score 0):

We can construct a deterministic finate automta for the given language L={a^n a^n b^m | m,n>=0} . So the given language is regular